# C# обновление ячеек на форме при быстрой генерации событий обновления

Tags: c#

Есть такой метод, в нем от разных потоков приходят сведения о нужной ячейке на гриде , и в секунду таких обновлений и вызова этой функции может быть около 1000 раз , в общем в дебаге я вижу прорисовку на форме, а когда запускаю экзешник форма залагивает и в конце подсчета уже прорисовывается все , как решить проблему с прорисовкой ?

```
 async Task _present_logic_CellsUpdating(int row, int cell, string svalue, double ivalue)
            {
                this.Invoke
                    (new Action( () =>
                    {
                        if (ivalue != 0)
                        {
                            gridview.SetRowCellValue(row, gridview.Columns[cell].FieldName, ivalue);
                        }
                    }));
            }
```

Comment: Вместо прямого вызова GUI-компонента через Invoke пишите данные из потоков в потокобезопасную очередь, а в отдельном потоке следите за этой очередью и обновляйте GUI. Причём обновление, естественно, не следует делать часто. Например, пару раз в секунду. То есть часть данных будет отбрасываться.

Comment: Да, ещё можно попробовать в лоб: у всех компонентов включить двойную буферизацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потокобезопасная очередь, оказалась лучшим решением